# Energy needed to evaporate 1kg of water at 115ºC at 170 kPa?

Tags: thermodynamics

So how do i find out how much energy is needed to evaporate 1kg of water at 115ºC at 170 kPa? Not really sure how things changes with pressure

Comment: Steam tables are the place to go...

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate it from the saturated steam tables for the saturation temperature of 115 C, which corresponds to the saturation pressure of 169 kPa. The column of interest is the enthalpy for evaporation.

Hope this  helps.

Comment: Notan, when you specify the ambient pressure, the boiling temperature of water is fixed.  Likewise, when you specify the boiling temperature, the pressure at which boiling occurs is fixed.  I don't know if the boiling information in your question "matches", but it is over-specified.

Comment: @DavidWhite David, yes it is over specified, but it does match.